# Laravel 5.6.20 routes with same url in different groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I have a `user` group and an `admin` role for my users.

What I want:

A different controller action for the same same URL. I thought the following would be nice, but this doesn't work.

At the moment, when I login as an admin, I get an exception that I'm not allowed to view the page.

`routes/web.php`

```
Route::group( [
    'middleware' => [ 'auth', \App\Http\Middleware\UserLastActivity::class ],
    'domain'     => parse_url( env( 'APP_URL' ), PHP_URL_HOST )
], function () {

    Route::group( [
        'middleware' => [ \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class ]
    ], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('home');
    } );


    Route::group( [
        'middleware' => [ \App\Http\Middleware\User::class ]
    ], function () {
        Route::get( '/', 'CvController@index' )->name( 'home' );
    } );
} );
```

`Http/Middleware/User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class User {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next ) {
        if ( \Auth::user()->role->id === \App\User::ROLE_USER ) {
            return $next( $request );
        }
        abort( 401 );
    }
}
```

`Http/Middleware/Admin.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( \Auth::user()->role->id === \App\User::ROLE_ADMIN ) {
            return $next( $request );
        }

        abort( 401, __('messages.http.unauthorized') );
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

To be clear:

**When a user has role_id 1 (admin):** the route `/` should perform `AdminController@index`

**When a user has role_id 2 (user):** the route `/` should perform `CvController@index`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to **re-think your routes**, since this isn't **good design** if you want to follow standards. You can have same url with different controllers when petition is different(post,get,put,etc).

Couldn't you put the logic of what has to be done depending on the user role inside the controller? Example:

`Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');`

Then in the index of UserController ->

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role->id == 1) :
       //do X
    else : 
      //do y
    endif;
}
```